# Need to click twice to call the function React MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have 3 text fields that I pass the entered values to 3 variables to make an API call later.
when I click the submit button it needs to click twice to make the submission of the entered data.
I need to pass the data with the validations if the entered data is validated(Ex: Blank/email is ok/10 digit mobile no)
following is my code.

```
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            userName: "",
            email: "",
            mobile: "",
            guestName: "",
            guestEmail: "",
            guestMobile: "",
        }
    
        this.submitData = this.submitData.bind(this);
    }
return(
    
                        <TextField
                            autoFocus
                            required 
                            margin="dense"
                            id="Username"
                            label="Name"
                            type="text"
                            value={this.state.userName}
                            onChange={this.setUsername.bind(this)}
                            // fullWidth
                        /><br/>
                        <TextField
                            // autoFocus
                            required 
                            margin="dense"
                            id="email"
                            label="Email"
                            type="email"
                            // fullWidth
                            value={this.state.email}
                            onChange={this.setEmail.bind(this)}
                        /><br/>
                        <TextField
                            required 
                            // autoFocus
                            margin="dense"
                            id="mobile"
                            label="Mobile"
                            type="mobile"
                            // fullWidth
                            value={this.state.mobile}
                            onChange={this.setMobile.bind(this)}
                        />
    
    setUsername = event =>{
            this.setState({
                userName: event.target.value
            });
    }
    
    setEmail = event =>{
        this.setState({
          email: event.target.value
        });
    }
    
    setMobile = event => {
        this.setState({
          mobile: event.target.value
        })
    }
    
    submitData(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            guestName: this.state.userName,
            guestEmail: this.state.email,
            guestMobile: this.state.mobile,
        })
        if(this.state.guestName === ''){
            alert('Please enter Name')
        } else {
            this.getRefCode();
        }
        console.log(this.state.guestName)
        console.log(this.state.userName)
    };

getRefCode(e){
    console.log('hi')
    const firstname = this.state.guestName
    const lastname = "fonseka"
    const email = this.state.guestEmail
    const mobile = this.state.guestMobile
    let custData = []
    custData.push(firstname, lastname, email, mobile);
    let customerData = {
        "firstName": firstname,
        "lastName": lastname,
        "email": email,
        "mobileNumber": mobile
      }

      let seatDetails = [];
      let seatNos = [];
      seatNos = selection.seats.split(',')
      let seatCatObj = {
          "seatCategoryId" : parseInt(selection.seatType),
          "seatNumbers" : seatNos,
          "adultCount" : parseInt(qty.length),
          "childCount" : parseInt(0)
      }
      seatDetails.push(seatCatObj);
    fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_BASE_URL}/v1/booking`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'client_token': 'ebd86470-7e90-4ece-9e89-1b6d4d2cbb61',
            'access_token': 'FFF',
        },
        
        body: JSON.stringify({
            // userId: 505,
            movieId: parseInt(selection.eventId),
            venueId: parseInt(selection.venueId),
            showtimeId: parseInt(selection.showId),
            movieDate: (selection.showDate),
            seatDetails: seatDetails,
            customerDetails: customerData,
        })
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) =>{
      console.log(data)
      if(data.success){
        this.setState({
            refCode: data.data.refcode,
            dataLoaded: true,
            refStatus: data.success
          })
          console.log(this.state.refCode)
          const totPrice = selection.price * qty.length
        window.location.href = `${process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_BASE_URL_PAYMENT}?userId=${505}&reference=${this.state.refCode}&amount=${totPrice}&currency=LKR&returnUrl=${encodeURIComponent(returUrl)}&cardId=${this.state.cardNo}`
      } else {
        console.log('booking failed')
        window.location.href = '#/BookingFailed?error=2'
      }
      }).catch((err) => console.log(err))          
}
)
```

Comment: Can you show the submit button code as well please?

Comment: `getRefCode` is the function i use